# Highchart merge won't enable labels in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with Highcharts - I am trying to take an existing chart, merge it into a new one, alter a few properties and then show it.

The problem I'm getting is that I can't seem to enable the xAxis labels in the copied chart. If I turn them on in the original chart they exist in the copied one, but there seems no way of altering the enabled state. A JSFiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/liamfl/a7xvfyg6/

The code is as follows:

```
var chart_PortfolioDetailsDistribution;
var popupChart;

$(document).ready(function () {
    chart_PortfolioDetailsDistribution = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{animation:false,renderTo:'smallchart3'}
        ,title:{text:'Distribution'}
        ,tooltip:{headerFormat:'',pointFormat:'<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}'}
        ,legend:{enabled:false}
        ,credits:{enabled:false}
        ,plotOptions:{series:{animation:false,borderWidth:0,dataLabels:{format:'<b>{point.y}</b>'}
        ,groupPadding:0,pointPadding:0}
    }
    ,yAxis:{
        title:{text:null}
    }
    ,xAxis:{
        labels:{enabled:false,rotation:-90}
        ,title:{text:null}
        ,type:'category'
    }
    ,series:[{
        data:[['<-10%',0],['<-5%',3],['<-2.5%',3],['<-1%',2],['<0%',10],['>0%',3],['>1%',0],['>2.5%',0],['>5%',0],['>10%',0]],
        name:'Portfolio',
        type:'column'}]
    });

    popupChart = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(chart_PortfolioDetailsDistribution.options, {
            chart: { renderTo: 'smallchart4' },
            xAxis: { labels: { enabled: true }},
            legend: { enabled: true },
            plotOptions: { series: { dataLabels: { enabled: true } }}
        }));
});
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped (which for me is a natural state...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xAxis` returned by `.options` is actually an array of objects.  So, when you merge it you need to merge with an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/a7xvfyg6/1/

```
Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(chart_PortfolioDetailsDistribution.options, {
        chart: { renderTo: 'smallchart4' },
        xAxis: [{ labels: { enabled: true }}],
        legend: { enabled: true },
        plotOptions: { series: { dataLabels: { enabled: true } }}
    }));
```